# Whether to show Common Item Dialog or GetOpenFileName? (Win32 API)

Tags: c++, c, file, winapi, dialog

I am wondering if I am reinventing the wheel here.

In essence, the new Common Item Dialog file browser is much better than the old GetOpenFileName() version.  If a user is on Vista+ operating system I want to use the new dialog, yet still have a function for the old dialog on XP, etc..

So I am wondering if I should create a function like this.

```
BOOL ShowOpenFileDialog(_Out_ LPTSTR szBuffer, _In_ UINT iBufferSize)
{
    static DWORD dwMajorVersion = 0;

    if (!dwMajorVersion)
        dwMajorVersion = (DWORD)(LOBYTE(LOWORD(GetVersion())));

    if (dwMajorVersion >= 6)    // Vista+
        return ShowNewOpenFileDialog(szBuffer, iBufferSize); // show common item

    return ShowOldOpenFileDialog(szBuffer, iBufferSize);  // fall back to old dialog
}
```

Also a followup is the common item C++ only?

Comment: For new code I'm not sure I'd worry about compatibility with XP or older.

Comment: I would agree.  The only problem is I will be using this tool on client machines, many of whom still have legacy systems.  Where I can use the new dialog it will make my overall happiness in life so much better.

Comment: Don't base it on the version number. Base it on whether `CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog)` succeeds. Version checks are hard to get right.

Comment: Especially considering that `GetVersion/Ex()` is now [deprecated in Windows 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302074.aspx) onwards, and thus lies without proper manifesting. Raymond is right, you should be checking if `CLSID_IFileOpenDialog` is available and use it if so, falling back to `GetOpenFileName()` when needed.

Comment: It may be easiest to call GetOpenFileName and let the system map that to the new common item dialog.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Raymond Chen said, you should not be relying on version numbers, rely on the availability of functionality instead, eg:

```
BOOL ShowOpenFileDialog(_Out_ LPTSTR szBuffer, _In_ UINT iBufferSize)
{
    IFileDialog *pfd = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IFileDialog, (void**)&pfd);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // use IFileDialog as needed...
        pfd->Release();
    }
    else
    {
        // use GetOpenFileName() as needed...
    }
}
```

And no, `IFileDialog` is not specific to C++ only.  It can be used by any language that supports COM, including C, C++, Delphi, VisualBasic, etc.

Comment: It's worth noting that it isn't quite this straightforward.  If your build targets XP then it won't compile.  If it targets Vista then your program may well have issues running on Windows XP.  Manually copying definitions from the future while targeting XP is reliable but tedious.  There may be a slicker method.